# Determine version of sbt autoPlugin

Tags: playframework, sbt

How can I check which version of an sbt autoPlugin is currently in the build?

For example, Play framework provides the `sbt-native-packager` plugin which can be added to the build by placing `enablePlugins(SbtNativePackager)` in `build.sbt`. Is there a way to determine which version of `sbt-native-packager` is being used from sbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the nicest, but here's one way:

```
sbt
> reload plugins
> consoleProject
scala> ((managedClasspath in Compile).eval
     |   map (_.data.toString)
     |   filter (_ contains "native")
     |   foreach println
     | )
/Users/dnw/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/jars/sbt-native-packager-1.0.1.jar
```

Comment: Thanks! That works when there's an explicit dependency in `project/plugins.sbt` but doesn't seem to find anything if provided from another project, like Play.

Comment: That was a Play project, without `sbt-native-packager` declared in `project/plugins.sbt`. I think you're getting `managedClasspath` confused with `libraryDependencies`.

Comment: How right you are. I should have copy pasted directly. Mea culpa.

Comment: A little easier to type, if you're willing to CTRL-F through the output: `;reload plugins;show compile:managedClasspath; reload return`